# Reshape input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28, 1]) to input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28])

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I have a variable :

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28, 1])
```

I want to convert it to the above shape. I'm doing it with help of tflearn.reshape but it isn't working properly. Here is the code "

```
network = tflearn.reshape(network,(-1, 28, 28))
```

I don't want to redeclare it to shape [None,28,28] as I have elements in it. Any help on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the shape you put. it should be [-1,28,28] format.

So your code will be :

```
network = tflearn.reshape(network,[-1, 28, 28])
```

Regards